# retrieve child values of a child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

i have a user generated by auto id , who has a child node "post" ,which further has child nodes genrated by auto id having further childs of "Text" and "Time"

JSON :

USERS:

- simpleLogin1

  - name : "mike"
  - email : "mike@abc.com"
  - posts

    - iagsdasgdasvdasdasd

      - text : "first post"
      - time : "7/8/2015"
    - izxczxvzvqweebxcv

      - text : "second post"
      - time : "7/8/2015"
    - iagqweoqiemzxcxcz

      - text : "third post"
      - time : "7/8/2015"

now the question is how do i access the post's child only the one i want , lets say i set a condition that when string matches the string in Text do something, but how do i access the post's child ??? help i am new to swift and firebase

Answer (score 0):

If talk about solution on Swift 2, very raw view:

```
let dict = ["simpleLogin1": ["name": "mike", "email": "email", "posts": ["iagsdasgdasvdasdasd": ["text": "first", "time": "7/8/2015"], "izxczxvzvqweebxcv": ["text": "second post", "time": "7/8/2015"], "iagqweoqiemzxcxcz": ["text": "third post", "time": "7/8/2015"]]]]

    for (key, value) in dict["simpleLogin1"]!["posts"]! as! [String: AnyObject] where (value["text"] as! String).hasSuffix("post") {
        print(key)
    }
```

But better use, *switch* statements in cycle body and safe model of retrieving data, optional chaining for example.